# Single quotes around list elements that should be floats

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am asked to "return a list of tuples containing the subset name (as a string) and a list of floating point data values".

My code is:

```
def load_data(filename):

    fileopen = open(filename)
    result_open=[]
    for line in fileopen:
        answer = (line.strip().split(","))
        result_open.append((answer[0],(answer[1:])))
    return result_open
```

However, when I run the code, the following appears:

```
[('Slow Loris', [' 21.72', ' 29.3', ' 20.08', ' 29.98', ' 29.85', ' 26.22', ' 19......)]
```

Is there anyway to change the tuple to appear without the apostrophes?  I want it to look like:

```
[('Slow Loris', [21.72, 29.3, 20.08, 29.98, 29.85, 6.22, 19......)]
```

Comment: The apostrophes indicate to you that the type is a string you might want to try to convert these to a float.

Answer (score 1):

`line` is a string, and `line.strip().split(",")` is a list of strings. You need to convert the string values into `float` or `Decimal` values. One way would be:

```
result_open.append((answer[0], [float(val) for val in answer[1:]]))
```

That will raise an exception on values that can't be converted to a float, so you should think about how you want to handle such input.